# PIVOT two tables in SQL server without aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Problem converting rows to columns.

My structure is like this:

```
SELECT 
    [ID_KPI]
   ,[KPI_VALUE]
FROM [dbo].[FACT_KPI]

SELECT 
    ID_KPI
   ,KPI_LABEL
FROM [dbo].[DIM_KPI]
```

[INPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5MNT.png)

And the output I'm trying to achieve

```
SELECT 
    [nb_departure]
   ,[nb_arrival]
   ,[headcount]
FROM [dbo].[FACT_HR]
```

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WblxH.png)

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

You can use pivot as below:

```
Select nb_departure, nb_arrival, headcount from (
    Select d.KPI_LABEL, f.KPI_VALUE
    , RowN = Row_Number() over(order by d.id_kpi)
        from dbo.Fact_KPI f
        join dbo.Dim_KPI d
        on f.ID_KPI = d.ID_KPI
) a
pivot (max(kpi_value) for kpi_label in ([nb_departure],[nb_arrival],[headcount])) p
```

Output as below:

```
+--------------+------------+-----------+
| nb_departure | nb_arrival | headcount |
+--------------+------------+-----------+
| 25           | NULL       | NULL      |
| 30           | NULL       | NULL      |
| NULL         | 15         | NULL      |
| NULL         | 7          | NULL      |
| NULL         | NULL       | 12        |
| NULL         | NULL       | 13        |
+--------------+------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a CTE or derived table and some conditional aggregation. I have no idea what you mean without aggregation and I am not sure if this possible without aggregation:

CTE:

```
CREATE TABLE FACT_KPI (ID_KPI int, KPI_VALUE int)
CREATE TABLE DIM_KPI (ID_KPI int, KPI_LABEL varchar(25))

INSERT INTO FACT_KPI VALUES (1,25)
                        ,(1,30)
                        ,(2,15)
                        ,(2,7)
                        ,(3,12)
                        ,(3,13)

INSERT INTO DIM_KPI VALUES (1, 'nb_departure')
                       ,(2, 'nb_arrival')
                       ,(3, 'headcount')



;WITH cte_example
AS
(SELECT F_KPI.ID_KPI, KPI_VALUE, KPI_LABEL
FROM FACT_KPI F_KPI
INNER JOIN DIM_KPI ON F_KPI.ID_KPI = DIM_KPI.ID_KPI)

SELECT CASE WHEN ID_KPI = 1 THEN KPI_VALUE END AS nb_departure,
   CASE WHEN ID_KPI = 2 THEN KPI_VALUE END AS nb_arrival,
   CASE WHEN ID_KPI = 3 THEN KPI_VALUE END AS headcount
FROM cte_example
```

Derived table:

```
CREATE TABLE FACT_KPI (ID_KPI int, KPI_VALUE int)
CREATE TABLE DIM_KPI (ID_KPI int, KPI_LABEL varchar(25))

INSERT INTO FACT_KPI VALUES (1,25)
                        ,(1,30)
                        ,(2,15)
                        ,(2,7)
                        ,(3,12)
                        ,(3,13)

INSERT INTO DIM_KPI VALUES (1, 'nb_departure')
                       ,(2, 'nb_arrival')
                       ,(3, 'headcount')
SELECT CASE WHEN ID_KPI = 1 THEN KPI_VALUE END AS nb_departure,
   CASE WHEN ID_KPI = 2 THEN KPI_VALUE END AS nb_arrival,
   CASE WHEN ID_KPI = 3 THEN KPI_VALUE END AS headcount
FROM       
(SELECT F_KPI.ID_KPI, KPI_VALUE, KPI_LABEL
FROM FACT_KPI F_KPI
INNER JOIN DIM_KPI ON F_KPI.ID_KPI = DIM_KPI.ID_KPI) FACT_KPI
```

Other notes, please use an ASCII table next time and please read what [Sean Lange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813116/sean-lange) has commented.